# Upgrade realm-js from v6 to v10

Tags: realm, realm-js

**Update**

I found the [release notes](https://github.com/realm/realm-js/releases/tag/v10.0.0) when it comes to v10.0.0 and here's the place where I find the breaking changes. I guess this should be enough?

**Initial question**

I want to upgrade the realm library version we're using (v6.1.0) to latest stable one (v10.4.0) in our react-native project.

Since I didn't find any upgrade docs from v6 to v10 info, gonna ask it here: is there any change that we have to be aware of, like api methods that are not supported anymore?

If so, a readme with the steps of upgrading to this version would be awesome.

Thanks!

Comment: By any chance, did you get the solution?